# Need of using MACROS like module_init and module_exit while writing Loadable Kernel Modules

Tags: macros, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

What is the need of using MACROs like  `module_init` and `module_exit` while writing Loadable Kernel Modules? Also, Why are we using MACROs like `__init` or `__exit`. Even though we can do the job without using them.

1. Without MACROS

   ```
    /*
    Without using MACROS
    Date: 14 Dec 2014
    */
    #include <linux/module.h>
    #include <linux/kernel.h>
    int init_module(void){
        printk(KERN_ALERT "This is our first program.");
        return 0;
    }
    void cleanup_module(void){
        printk(KERN_ALERT "End of our first program.");
    }
   ```
2. With MACROs

   ```
    /* 
    Edited first.c; Added macros module_init and module_exit
    Date: 14 Dec 2014
    */
    #include <linux/module.h>
    #include <linux/kernel.h>
    #include <linux/init.h>

    static int __init first_init(void)
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "This is our first program.");
        return 0;
    }

    static void __exit first_exit(void)
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "End of our first program.");
    }

    module_init(first_init);
    module_exit(first_exit);
   ```

What is the difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [module\_init and init\_module of linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218320/module-init-and-init-module-of-linux)

Answer (score 6):

`module_{init,exit}()` adds the necessary boilerplate to initialize / cleanup the module and run the entry / exit code, when the module file is loaded / unloaded into or from the kernel space.

`__init` is telling kernel that this function is executed once and
never come back mainly for built-in drivers while `module_init()` is to initialize the module when it is being insmod.

[Refer Rubini & Corbet](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch02.html#t4)

"

The attribute __init, , will cause the initialization function
to be discarded, and its memory reclaimed, after initialization is
complete. It only works, however, for built-in drivers; it has no
effect on modules. __exit, instead, causes the omission of the marked
function when the driver is not built as a module; again, in modules,
it has no effect.

The use of __init (and __initdata for data items) can reduce the
amount of memory used by the kernel. There is no harm in marking
module initialization functions with __init, even though currently
there is no benefit either. Management of initialization sections has
not been implemented yet for modules, but it's a possible enhancement
for the future.

"