# Insmod is not working

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

`insmod`/`rmmod` doesn't recognize the arguments. Even `insmod` without any argument also gets executed. It looks like only command is recognized by the system.

Through `insmod` command kernel module can be inserted dynamically but when I do `insmod testStub.ko`, nothing is happening. Neither do I see my module in `lsmod` result nor any `printk` messages that I have written in my `testStub.c`, in `dmesg`.

`lsmod`/`modprobe -l`  also don't show any output.

`lsmod` command is supposed to show all running modules .in my system it gives no output.

This is `testStub.c`:

```c
#include <linux/module.h> /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h> /* Needed for KERN_INFO */

int init_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_EMERG "Module Attached");
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Module Detached!\n");
}
```

This is Makefile:

```
obj-m += testStub.o

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking or experiencing.  Try giving example command and responses.  That should help overcome your English limitations.

Comment: @nategoose .I have added the details.now does  description make you understand the problem ?

Comment: No. People reading your question should be able to attempt to repeat the output.  What does `cat /proc/modules` print?

Comment: What value is returned by `insmod sample.ko`? (Can be viewed by executing  `echo $?` after it in the same terminal). Also, name and version of your distro would be helpfull, same for kernel version you load.

Comment: @Tsyvarev insmod sample.ko returns 0.

System- Linux(Ubuntu 14.04 ),
Release-3.13.0-45-generic,
Machine- x86_64

Comment: @nategoose cat /proc/modules prints all running modules. But my sample module is not there.

Comment: Try to add this in your code:`module_init(init_module);`

Comment: @shuofoi Not required.
go through the following link.
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/c147.htm

Comment: As `insmod` works even without arguments... What output of `insmod --version` is? And where `insmod` is placed in the filesystem (output of `which insmod`)? BTW, your question tells about `sample.ko` module and `sample.c` source, but according to your code, these should be `testStub.ko` and `testStub.c` correspondingly.

Comment: insmod --version = no output,
find / -name insmod =
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/insmod,
/usr/lib/klibc/bin/insmod,
/sbin/insmod.
Sorry. i have updated proper file names in the question.

Comment: Probably, you have another program, named `insmod`. One, which loads kernel modules, is `/sbin/insmod`. Try to use it explicitely: `/sbin/insmod testStub.ko`.

Comment: Calling functions `init_module`/`cleanup_module` is not enough for Linux >2.6, you need to use `module_init`/`module_exit` macro like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218320/module-init-and-init-module-of-linux

Comment: @myaut: Question (and answers to it) you refer to just say, that both variants are correct. I have checked `init_module` and `cleanup_module` with 3.18 kernel - they work as expected.

Comment: @ShailendraSaxena What does `which insmod` output?  Also, run the `file` and `ls -l` on what is returned.  If `insmod` is a symbolic link then follow the link so that we can find out what's really being run.  If you find a shell script, then look at and possibly share the text of it.

Comment: @nategoose which insmod -/sbin/insmod; insmod is a symbolic link and linked to /bin/kmod.
ls -l /sbin/insmod;
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Sep 11  2014 /sbin/insmod -> /bin/kmod.

Comment: file /sbin/insmod -/sbin/insmod: symbolic link to `/bin/kmod'

Comment: @nategoose  vi  /bin/kmod; this file is empty. who deleted the content of this file ? that's why insmod is not taking any action. how to recover this file ?

Comment: @ShailendraSaxena Why would you choose to use `vi` to check the contents of that file? It's likely a binary file of some type, and at best you should expect jibberish.  Run `file` and `ls -l` on it.

Comment: @ShailendraSaxena Is the computer that you're using your computer?  Is it possible that you're running in a `chroot`ed login?

Comment: @nategoose yes i have root access. I can directly login as a root into the machine. Yes i was expecting jibberish in the file /bin/kmod like /bin/grep has. it should have binary content that gets executed on calling insmod.

Comment: @ShailendraSaxena I wouldn't expect running an empty file to fail so silently. From your home directory try `touch empty_file ; chmod +x empty_file ; ./empty_file`.  Your shell program should give you some type of error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your source file is missing **module license** this taints the kernel when you try to insert the module. add below line to your source code to make it work.

`MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");`