# MIPS32 router: module_init not called for kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, mips, busybox, mips32, buildroot

I'm developing a kernel module that I want to run on my router. The router model is DGN2200v2 by Netgear. It's running Linux 2.6.30 on MIPS. My problem is that when I load my module it seems that my `module_init` isn't getting called. I tried to narrow it down by modifying my `module_init` to return -3 (which indicates an error?) and `insmod` still reports success. I can see my module in the output of `lsmod`, but I don't see my `printk` output using `dmesg`.

For starters, I wanted to create the simplest possible module:

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

static int my_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_EMERG "init_module() called\n");
    return -3;
}

static void my_cleanup(void)
{
    printk(KERN_EMERG "cleanup_module() called\n");
}

module_init(my_init);
module_exit(my_cleanup);
```

This is the Makefile I'm using:

```
TOOLCHAIN=/home/user/buildroot-2016.08/output/host/usr/bin/mips-buildroot-linux-uclibc-
ARCH=mips
CC = $(TOOLCHAIN)gcc

KBUILD_CFLAGS:=.

EXTRA_CFLAGS := -I/home/user/buildroot-2016.08/output/build/linux-headers-2.6.30/include\
  -I/home/user/buildroot-2016.08/output/build/linux-headers-2.6.30/arch/mips/include/asm/mach-mipssim\
  -I/home/user/buildroot-2016.08/output/build/linux-headers-2.6.30/arch/mips/include/asm/mach-generic\
  -fno-pic -mno-abicalls -O2

obj-m := module.o
KDIR := /home/user/buildroot-2016.08/output/build/linux-headers-2.6.30
PWD := $(shell pwd)

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
```

I'm running `make` like so:

```
make ARCH=mips CROSS_COMPILE=/home/user/buildroot-2016.08/output/host/usr/bin/mips-buildroot-linux-uclibc-
```

which passes successfully.

As you can see, I'm using Buildroot which I (hopefully) configured correctly. I can paste my .config if needed.

I ran objdump on my module and didn't find a problem. In particular, the module_init symbol seems to point to the same place as my my_init function, and it seems to have the code I expect it to:

```
module.ko:     file format elf32-tradbigmips
module.ko
architecture: mips:isa32, flags 0x00000011:
HAS_RELOC, HAS_SYMS
start address 0x00000000
private flags = 50001001: [abi=O32] [mips32] [not 32bitmode] [noreorder]

MIPS ABI Flags Version: 0

ISA: MIPS32
GPR size: 32
CPR1 size: 0
CPR2 size: 0
FP ABI: Soft float
ISA Extension: None
ASEs:
    None
FLAGS 1: 00000001
FLAGS 2: 00000000

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .MIPS.abiflags 00000018  00000000  00000000  00000038  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA, LINK_ONCE_SAME_SIZE
  1 .reginfo      00000018  00000000  00000000  00000050  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA, LINK_ONCE_SAME_SIZE
  2 .note.gnu.build-id 00000024  00000018  00000018  00000068  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  3 .text         00000040  00000000  00000000  00000090  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
  4 .rodata.str1.4 00000038  00000000  00000000  000000d0  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  5 .modinfo      0000005c  00000000  00000000  00000108  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  6 .data         00000000  00000000  00000000  00000170  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  7 .gnu.linkonce.this_module 0000014c  00000000  00000000  00000170  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, DATA, LINK_ONCE_DISCARD
  8 .bss          00000000  00000000  00000000  000002c0  2**4
                  ALLOC
  9 .comment      00000040  00000000  00000000  000002c0  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
 10 .pdr          00000040  00000000  00000000  00000300  2**2
                  CONTENTS, RELOC, READONLY
 11 .gnu.attributes 00000010  00000000  00000000  00000340  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
 12 .mdebug.abi32 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000350  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
SYMBOL TABLE:
00000000 l    d  .MIPS.abiflags 00000000 .MIPS.abiflags
00000000 l    d  .reginfo   00000000 .reginfo
00000018 l    d  .note.gnu.build-id 00000000 .note.gnu.build-id
00000000 l    d  .text  00000000 .text
00000000 l    d  .rodata.str1.4 00000000 .rodata.str1.4
00000000 l    d  .modinfo   00000000 .modinfo
00000000 l    d  .data  00000000 .data
00000000 l    d  .gnu.linkonce.this_module  00000000 .gnu.linkonce.this_module
00000000 l    d  .bss   00000000 .bss
00000000 l    d  .comment   00000000 .comment
00000000 l    d  .pdr   00000000 .pdr
00000000 l    d  .gnu.attributes    00000000 .gnu.attributes
00000000 l    d  .mdebug.abi32  00000000 .mdebug.abi32
00000000 l    df *ABS*  00000000 module.c
00000000 l     F .text  0000002c my_init
0000002c l     F .text  00000014 my_cleanup
00000000 l       .rodata.str1.4 00000000 $LC0
0000001c l       .rodata.str1.4 00000000 $LC1
00000000 l    df *ABS*  00000000 module.mod.c
00000000 l     O .modinfo   00000023 __mod_srcversion23
00000024 l     O .modinfo   00000009 __module_depends
00000030 l     O .modinfo   0000002c __mod_vermagic5
00000000 g     O .gnu.linkonce.this_module  0000014c __this_module
0000002c g     F .text  00000014 cleanup_module
00000000 g     F .text  0000002c init_module
00000000         *UND*  00000000 printk



Disassembly of section .MIPS.abiflags:

00000000 <.MIPS.abiflags>:
   0:   00002001    movf    a0,zero,$fcc0
   4:   01000003    0x1000003
    ...
  10:   00000001    movf    zero,zero,$fcc0
  14:   00000000    nop

Disassembly of section .reginfo:

00000000 <.reginfo>:
   0:   a2000014    sb  zero,20(s0)
    ...
  14:   00007fef    0x7fef

Disassembly of section .note.gnu.build-id:

00000018 <.note.gnu.build-id>:
  18:   00000004    sllv    zero,zero,zero
  1c:   00000014    0x14
  20:   00000003    sra zero,zero,0x0
  24:   474e5500    c1  0x14e5500
  28:   c8e5d654    lwc2    $5,-10668(a3)
  2c:   cb477d3d    lwc2    $7,32061(k0)
  30:   dfa48d71    ldc3    $4,-29327(sp)
  34:   c2ea16da    ll  t2,5850(s7)
  38:   f6bcae7d    sdc1    $f28,-20867(s5)

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <init_module>:
   0:   27bdffe8    addiu   sp,sp,-24
   4:   3c040000    lui a0,0x0
            4: R_MIPS_HI16  $LC0
   8:   3c020000    lui v0,0x0
            8: R_MIPS_HI16  printk
   c:   afbf0014    sw  ra,20(sp)
  10:   24420000    addiu   v0,v0,0
            10: R_MIPS_LO16 printk
  14:   0040f809    jalr    v0
  18:   24840000    addiu   a0,a0,0
            18: R_MIPS_LO16 $LC0
  1c:   8fbf0014    lw  ra,20(sp)
  20:   2402fffd    li  v0,-3
  24:   03e00008    jr  ra
  28:   27bd0018    addiu   sp,sp,24
```

`modinfo` output also matches what I expect (same `modinfo` output as for another .ko that's found on the router, except for the `srcversion` which my module has but the other module on the router doesn't):

```
filename:       /home/user/module/module.ko
srcversion:     B0BADBA395A121CF49B74DC
depends:        
vermagic:       2.6.30 mod_unload MIPS32_R1 32BIT
```

It's entirely possible that I messed something up in my Buildroot configuration, or something doesn't quite match the CPU type of the router, but my init code is so minimal that I'm out of ideas as to what could be wrong.

Comment: First of all, both of your module functions must take `void` as param. In pure C, `function()` and `function(void)` are two different signatures. Second error: you need to add `;` after each `module_init()` and `module_exit()`.

Comment: @SamProtsenko Thanks for the suggestions, Sam. Unfortunately even after fixing these two issues (I modified the source code in my question accordingly) I get the same results. Any other thoughts on what could be wrong, or how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: You mentioned that: `I can see my module in the output of lsmod`, which I tend to believe (I mean, the module was loaded after all). So try to replace `printk()` in your init function with something like `BUG()` or `BUG_ON()`. This way you will see the effect instantly (after loading your module). Also, try to compare `dmesg` output before and after loading your module. There might be some hints in it.

Comment: @SamProtsenko Adding a `BUG()` call as the first line of the `my_init` method change nothing - the module still gets loaded successfully while printing nothing into `dmesg`. In fact, there is no new line in `dmesg`'s output as a result of the `insmod` call. Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot further?

Comment: Try to add module license (GPL), like it stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30973849/3866447).

Comment: @SamProtsenko No change even with GPL (please note that other modules on the router, that are successfully loaded, also do not have a GPL license). What would be a good way to diagnose this? How does the module loader locate the method to call upon initialization? I dug through the `objdump` output but everything seemed OK. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Well, there are several things at play here, each of which can lead to this behavior. I'd start with root causing (localizing what is the actual cause). From my POV it can be: wrong toolchain, wrong kernel sources (that you're building your module against), bad `insmod` tool, wrong code or Makefile of your module, wrong building procedure.

Comment: @SamProtsenko My hope was that by creating an absolutely minimal module, I could use `objdump` to see what was wrong. My assumption is that a loadable kernel module basically needs a `module_init` method and nothing else. So I can't figure out for the life of me what could be wrong here... Do you think I should try a different toolchain (which?)? Does something seem suspicious in the Makefile or code? I don't have a lot of experience developing kernel modules and I'm basically stuck here.

Comment: Use [this code](http://pastebin.com/ZTNH6Fr3) and [this Makefile](http://pastebin.com/5hcnMGJ0). Setup your shell environment like [this](http://pastebin.com/sqL4bDZV) and just run `make` in your module's directory. Note that you should use the same kernel sources that your kernel was built from, and also (preferably) the same toolchain. See what `file your_module.ko` shows. Then try to `insmod` it. Get back with results.

Comment: As for toolchain concerns: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33861485/3866447).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126435/discussion-between-ysk-and-sam-protsenko).

Comment: I'd check if modules on your router are [signed](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/module-signing.txt?id=refs/tags/v4.9-rc3).

Comment: @SamProtsenko Thanks for not forgetting me Sam :). I checked that too (took a module that works from the router, modified its module_init with a hex editor, tried to run it, and it still worked). I was in fact able to figure this out last night at long last... Will write an answer later today.

Comment: @SamProtsenko See my reply if you're interested in how this turned out. Hope you won't find it too disappointing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was related to a different kernel configuration between my development environment and the router. Specifically, my kernel was using `CONFIG_UNUSED_SYMBOLS` whereas the router's was not.

The reason this caused a problem even in a trivial module is that when the kernel loads a module it doesn't only look up the `module_init` symbol in the module's symbol table. Rather, it reads the `module` struct from the module (from the `.gnu.linkonce.this_module` section), and then calls the `init` module through that struct.

The offset of the `init` function pointer inside the `module` struct depends on the kernel configuration, which explains why the kernel can't find the `init` function if the configuration is different.

Thanks to Sam Protsenko for investing a lot of time in helping me crack this!